# simple multiple if statements in Perl not working

Tags: perl

I am using if statements and or operators in Perl. Whatever I type, it goes to else statement. What am I doing wrong?

```
my $ans = <STDIN>;
print "answer: $ans\n";

if ($ans eq "a" || $ans eq "b") {
    print "you entered a or b";
}
elsif ($ans eq "c" || $ans eq "d") {
    print "you entered c or d";
}
else {
    print "not a b c d ";
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to [`chomp;`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chomp.html). You're ending up with `"a\n"` in `$ans`, not just `"a"`.